# Spring security basic authentication configuration

Tags: spring, security, authentication

I've been trying to follow this tutorial :

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication

I have created a couple of rest endpoints like this :

```
@RestController
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    PostCommentService postCommentService;

    @Autowired
    PostService postService;

    @GetMapping("/comment")
    public PostComment getComment(@RequestParam Long id) {
       return postCommentService.findPostCommentById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/createPost")
    public void createPost(@RequestBody PostDTO body){
        postService.createPost(body);
    }
}
```

Now for security I am using spring like this:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

This is the config class for spring security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/comment").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(),
                BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

The CustomFilter looks like this:

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

And this is the AuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
@Component
public class MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx)
        throws IOException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm= + getRealmName() + ");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 - " + authEx.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet(){
        setRealmName("spring");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that whenever I try to send a POST request I end up getting this error message:

HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource

I have tried two approaches to send the request, one via postman

[image]

And the second one via curl:

curl -i --user admin:password --request POST --data {"text":"this is a new Post"} http://localhost:8080/createPost

I am at my wits' end here, hence the need to create this post. Any help will be much appreciated.

This is the curl response in case it might shed light on the matter:

1.1 401
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6FE84B06E90BE7F2348C0935FE3DA971; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm= + getRealmName() +
Content-Length: 75
Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 13:47:14 GMT

HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Spring Security comes with CSRF protection enabled by default (and for a good reason). You can read about Cross Site Request Forgery [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html). In your case the CsrfFilter detects missing or invalid CSRF token and you're getting the 401 response. The easiest way to make your example work would be to disable csrf-ing in your security configuration but, of course, you shouldn't do this in a real application.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/comment").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

    http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```